How to create a Word Doc Footer with multiple font/color styles using Vb.net
I'm trying to create a word doc Footer programmatically in vb.net that has 3 lines or more with 3 different font colors and font styles. I can only seem to get the first color and style to ‘stick’ the other 2 never change.  I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and am fairly new to coding with it. I would rather not use a macro.
The Footer should not be visible on the 1st page. The 2nd page should consist of only 2 of the lines and the all other will have all 3 lines. The third line will contain the Page numbers in the format of (Page number X of XX).
Here is what I have so far:
For Each section As Word.Section In moApp.Sections
   Dim footer As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter =  section.Footers(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
   Dim footerRange As Word.Range = section.Footers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
   footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdGray50
   footerRange.Font.Size = 12
   footerRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   footerRange.Text = "This is Line # 1"
   footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue
   footerRange.Font.Size = 10
   footerRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   footerRange.Text = "This is Line # 2"
   footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed
   footerRange.Font.Size = 8
   footerRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   footerRange.Text = "This is Line # 3 that will include the page numbers"
Next

When I run this my results display All 3 lines with the same font and style in the Footer. I need them a 3 different ones. Any help is appreciated!

Why not simply use the features built into Word. Create a Template built the way you want. Save the footer you want as a Footer Building Block. Doing this with code is the hard way! https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm -- https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#StoreBuildingBlocks

Charles, I would probably do this as a last resort. I just wanted to finish of the final code by created the footer programmatically like the rest of the document.

Your problem is that you are assigning values to properties, and then you are overriding them with other values, resulting in only the last value written being displayed.
Here is a simpler example:
Dim x As Integer = 0
x = 1
x = 2

Despite all the other values assigned to x, only the last one assigned (the x = 2) will have any effect on the final value. x is going to always be 2 after those three lines are run because that was the last value assigned. Just because you might run those lines more than once doesn't change that.
So, to bring this back to your problem, I'm going to subdivide part of the inside of your For Each loop into three sections:
   footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdGray50
   footerRange.Font.Size = 12
   footerRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   footerRange.Text = "This is Line # 1"

   footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue
   footerRange.Font.Size = 10
   footerRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   footerRange.Text = "This is Line # 2"

   footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed
   footerRange.Font.Size = 8
   footerRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   footerRange.Text = "This is Line # 3 that will include the page numbers"

These sections are run consecutively in the order they are ordered in. So, similar to the previous example, each one of these will have one value assigned to it, and then a second value assigned to it, and then a third value which will be the value it ends with. Thus, the result of the combination of those three sections is the same as the result of the last without the two previous:
   footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed
   footerRange.Font.Size = 8
   footerRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
   footerRange.Text = "This is Line # 3 that will include the page numbers"

I'm guessing what you wanted to do would be something of this sort:
Dim sectionIdx As Integer = 0

For Each section As Word.Section In moApp.Sections
   Dim footer As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter =  section.Footers(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
   Dim footerRange As Word.Range = section.Footers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
   If sectionIdx = 0 Then
      footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdGray50
      footerRange.Font.Size = 12
      footerRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
      footerRange.Text = "This is Line # 1"
   ElseIf sectionIdx = 1 Then
      footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue
      footerRange.Font.Size = 10
      footerRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
      footerRange.Text = "This is Line # 2"
   ElseIf sectionIdx = 2 Then
      footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed
      footerRange.Font.Size = 8
      footerRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
      footerRange.Text = "This is Line # 3 that will include the page numbers"
   End If
   sectionIdx += 1
Next

I haven't tested in nor have I worked with VB.NET in years, so that is just my guess. The above may or may not work as intended. However, even if it doesn't, it doesn't invalidate the reason your code doesn't work, which I am much more certain of. So, even if it doesn't, you can probably find the solution on your own given what I have given you that is correct.
Bear in mind, even if it does function as intended, the above code will only work for the first three iterations of the For Each loop, so you'll probably have to do some string concatenation directly with sectionIdx if you want to be able to do all pages. I only made it only do the first three because that was what your original code seemed to be trying to do.

I appreciate that detailed answer. But it only shows the last line in red for each of the pages footer unfortunately. You are correct, I think it is overwriting it each time and the last set style is the winner. It looks like I need to the Footer within one loop, then start again... I just don't know how to apply multi colors...perhaps the foot is not indented to have multi colors? I wish I could treat it like HTML.. perhaps there is an HTML import I could use to get the style I want? Thanks for your help!

@Tommycod I think all the characters in the same range can only be set to the same font. Perhaps there is some way to subdivide a range? The documentation is here, but I wasn't able to find anything.

@Tommycod Have you looked at Range.InsertXML? That would be sort of like HTML.

the range division makes sense.. I also reviewed the docs and cant figure it out. I know it can be done in MS word manually but having a heck of a time trying to do it programmatically. It just seems like it would be a simple task... not so..and the MS Interop documentation is of little help. :(

I did take a look at the Range.InsertXML but I could not get the proper structure to show without the XML nesting. Any help with a basic 3 tiered color change would be greatly appreciated. I'm just not sure if this is the last resort(prior to a template or macro which I didn't want to do... thanks for your help!
